# Is there a way to let a element to follow a path in Windows Store App (Metro App)?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Does anyone know how to allow a element to follow a path in the Metro App platform? Like using `DoubleAnimationUsingPath`? Unfortunately, Metro apps don't support this function anymore. Is there an alternative?

I have drawn a path (line), and I wish that my image is able to move along the path which had been drawn once PointerReleased on the canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately, they removed all of the useful functionality from Paths; They're strictly visuals now. You'll have to create an animation in Blend to mimic moving along a path. Take a look here to get started with Blend animations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj155226.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Peter ! Appreciated your help !